# Sequence converges but Improper Integral diverges

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals, examples-counterexamples

Can someone give me an example of a sequence such that $$a_{n}=\int_{1}^{n}f(x)dx$$ converges but $$\int_{1}^{∞}f(x)dx$$ diverges.

Comment: I see that you have posted another question to prove the opposite.

Comment: Not the opposite... to prove that the converse holds, even if this direction doesn't. Still, to the OP; as in your other question: can you show us what **you** tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $a_n = \int_1^n \cos(2\pi x)\,dx.$

Comment: My sequence is $0,0,0,\dots$

Comment: Answer is correct -- upvoted for that. But I was actually on the verge on not doing it, just because the OP is not providing any effort, and answering her/him can only be an incentive to continue.

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to include some explanation, motivation, or suggestion of how you got this? As it stands, this is just a copy-pastable answer to a copy-pasted question.

Comment: I like my answer the way it is. Once you consider it and think of the graph of $\cos (2\pi x),$ I think the intuition is clear. As for "copy-pastable answer", gee thanks

Comment: @zhw. I think that if the OP had intuition about these things, they wouldn't have asked the question. As it stands, I don't think this is useful. (-1)

Comment: @DeepSea What is it you're trying to say, exactly?